# Freeradius expiration variable expanding

Tags: radius, freeradius

After looking into dozens of wiki's info pages and other resources, i'm unable to find a way on displaying the expiration date to a user.

My reply message: `Reply-Message := "Your account has expired on %{Expiration} go to ab.com for extending!"` Doesnt work. I can't seem to expand the variable Expiration in my database:

my expiration label is:
`Expiration := 05 Jun 2012 02:00`.

The expiration mod however does work, but i just can't show the expiration date. Is there any way to expand "custom database variables" in a radius environment, with freeradius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify the attribute with a list. There are three lists in the server, request, control, reply.

The use of request (default for unqualified attributes) and reply can be inferred from their names. Control (also called 'check' in older modules) holds attributes which affect the behaviour of the modules. `Expiration` is a control attribute so you need to qualify expansions involving it with `control:`

`Reply-Message := "Your account has expired on %{control:Expiration} go to ab.com for extending!"`